# Prevent multiple parallell AsyncTask's on API10?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, parallel-processing, threadpool

According to [the documentation for AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), it uses a pool of parallell threads on certain older API's:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

What if I truly want non-parallel execution even on pre-Honeycomb?

On newer API's, they end up running one after the other. Is there any way to get the same behaviour on pre-Honeycomb as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no, not with the API by itself.  It really only affects Donut, Eclair, Froyo and Gingerbread.  Instead of using `AsyncTask`, you could use your own thread pool executor with a single thread so it serializes things.  But, the API itself is different within the framework in versions prior to Honyecomb.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just making the code that's being called by the AsyncTask's `synchronized` and it seems to work.